# How to get a ValueError from merge with pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, merge, valueerror

I am trying to reverse engineer an error message.

In the code below I merge 2 dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
     'PB website': ["http://www.ghi.de", "http://www.jkl.de", "http://www.def.de", "http://www.abc.de", "http://www.xyz.de"],
     'PB match': [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
     'PB location': ["Süd 4", "Süd 2", "Süd 5", "Süd 3", "Süd 8"],
     'PB country': ['Deutschland', 'Deutschland', 'Deutschland', 'Deutschland', 'Deutschland'],
     })

processed_urls = ['http://www.abc.de', 'http://www.def.de', 'http://www.ghi.de', 'http://www.xyz.de', 'http://www.jkl.de']
flags = [False, True, True, False, True]

processed = pd.merge(left=data.loc[data['PB website'].isin(processed_urls)],
                    right=pd.DataFrame({'url': processed_urls, 'verlinkt': flags}),
                    left_on='PB website', right_on='url', how='right')

processed
```

The result looks like this:

```
    PB website     PB match PB location  PB country         url         verlinkt
0   http://www.abc.de   24     Süd 3    Deutschland    http://www.abc.de    False
1   http://www.def.de   23     Süd 5    Deutschland    http://www.def.de    True
2   http://www.ghi.de   21     Süd 4    Deutschland    http://www.ghi.de    True
3   http://www.xyz.de   25     Süd 8    Deutschland    http://www.xyz.de    False
4   http://www.jkl.de   22     Süd 2    Deutschland    http://www.jkl.de    True
```

Now I want to change the code in a way that I get the following error message:

*ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat*

I know, in order to do so, `PB website` and `url` have to have different format. But for some reason I can not generate the `ValueError` mentioned above.

I am using pandas version 1.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible - neither `PB website` nor `url` can be represented as floats, except of course as just `NaNs`. In this case you can use

```
processed = pd.merge(left=data.loc[data['PB website'].isin(processed_urls)],
                    right=pd.DataFrame({'url': processed_urls, 'verlinkt': flags}).assign(url=lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.url, 'coerce')),
                    left_on='PB website', right_on='url', how='right')
```

which throws a `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`.

Comment: For some reason the log-files in production show a ``ValueError`` at exactly this position... Would it be possible that the dataframes ``left`` and ``right`` contain any other additional value (not shown in the example) that could lead to this particular ``ValueError``? Maybe some NaN values?

Comment: @PParker I don't think so: as soon as minimum one row entry of a column is a string, the column type will be object. For a float column, all entries must be floats including special float values like np.nan or np.inf. If any of the two column to link on is of mixed type with some floats (i.e. an object column) you won't get a ValueError but there will just be NaN entries in the result.